# AngularJS vs Express template views - When to use

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, ejs

The answer to this question may become clearer to me as I continue learning about both technologies, but I've learned a little Angular and a little Express and the ejs view template.

I'm able to create the same html view using Angular directives as I am using ejs templates.

Is there an advantage to using one over the other, say in a situation where I am displaying all contents of an array. Angular's ng-repeat directive seems easy enough, but then I can do the same using inline js and ejs.